# Chromium displays square characters in Alpine docker container

Tags: docker, chromium, alpine-linux

I am following https://github.com/novaspirit/Alpine_xfce4_noVNC to run alpine in docker container. And I installed chromium by "apk add chromium". Chromium starts successfully but displays some characters in square boxes. It looks like I need to install some extra font, anyone knows?

alpine version 3.16
chromium version 102

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncGqT.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

following https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Fonts to install japanese/chinese lanuage packages fixes the problem.

```
apk add font-terminus font-noto font-noto-thai font-noto-tibetan font-ipa font-sony-misc font-daewoo-misc font-jis-misc
apk add font-isas-misc
```